# how to find the sum of these terms without the gamma function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, telescopic-series

While solving a problem based on integration, I arrived at the following

$$\sum\limits_{x = 1}^{38} \ln\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$

I'm supposed to prove that this is less than $\ln(99)$
in order to do that, I tried evaluating the summation on wolfram(as I don't know how to compute this by myself)
, but in the general form, wolfram uses the gamma function, which I don't know.

Comment: *Hint:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescope :)

Comment: Or look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1747383/42969

Comment: Thanks, is there any simple way t understand how the result was obtained?

Comment: $\ln\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) = \ln(x) - \ln(x+1)$. Do you know what a “telescoping sum“ is?

Comment: Btw, all terms in the sum are *negative,* therefore the sum is surely less than $\ln(99)$.

Comment: @MartinR, regarding you fist comment, informally, I go, but the only kind I'' familiar with is an infinite GP

Comment: and regarding your second comment, yeah, got it. That should have been obvious, thanks for pointing tha out?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a telescoping series:
$$
     \sum_{x=1}^{38}\ln\frac{x}{x+1} = \sum_{x=1}^{38}\ln x -\ln(x+1) \\
     = (\ln 1-\ln 2)+(\ln 2-\ln 3)+\cdots+(\ln 38-\ln 39) \\
     = \ln 1 - \ln 39 \\
     = -\ln 39.
$$

Comment: oh,OK. Thanks!!

Comment: @fhhh : If this answers your question, please select the checkmark next to the question to accept the answer. You can +1 if you particularly like the answer, but that is not necessary.

Comment: I already upvoted, but I was waiting for a day just incase, thanks and sorry